# Setting the camera button for different actions swift 3

Tags: mobile, swift3

I am creating an app where I open the camera as the first thing. I am able to do that. Once the user takes the photo, he is shown with two options, 'Use photo' or 'cancel'. My question is how can I write code in swift 3 to set the 'Use photo' button to my convenience like storing the photo to the gallery, or some other actions. Please suggest some code to do that. Thanks!

Below is the code I am using for opening the camera:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate,         UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {
        override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
            if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera) {
                let image = UIImagePickerController() 
                image.delegate = self  
                image.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera   
                image.allowsEditing = false
                self.present(image, animated: true)
            } else {
                print("This device does not support camera")
            }
        }
   }


  func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {  
    if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
        myImageView.image = image
    }
    else {
        //Error message
    }
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    print("camera is dismissed or not")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> My question is how can I write code in swift 3 to set the 'Use photo' button to my convenience like storing the photo to the gallery, or some other actions.

You're already setting `ViewController` as the image picker controller's delegate, so you just need to implement the [`image​Picker​Controller(_:​did​Finish​Picking​Media​With​Info:​)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiimagepickercontrollerdelegate/1619126-imagepickercontroller) method in `ViewController`.

Comment: I implemented the method, but my camera is not going off on click of 'use photo' button even though I have dismissed it. I have updated my post with the new code.